# where are created/save the data connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

While upgrade my npgsql version I create some new connections. Where are those save so I can delete it the unnecesary connections.

The original one is TrafficEntities that is ok because the data base is `Traffic` and the project is `GTracker`. Why the other only say  `(Traffic)` ??

[image]

Comment: See App.config or Web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `App.Config` file which will hold any contents of old/un-used connection strings/info.